# Missing template with format route option

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to play with Rails routes, and I came across format option that is giving me a headache.Here's the problem:
I have this route, where format is optional:

```
match '/message/:id(.:format)' => 'posts#index'
```

and it works for `/message/1`, `/message/1.blabla`, but when I use jpeg/gif/png or any other graphic format(`/message/1.jpeg`) I get `Template is missing error`, so I guess that format looks specifically for that kinds of extensions ? So, what is the purpose of format?

Answer (score 0):

You should define your **type** in **config/initializers/mime_types.rb**, for example:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/docx", :docx
```